# How do I make my treeview fit the frame in my notebook in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm actually new to using python. I just wanted to ask if how am I going to be able to make my treeview fit/expand automatically on the frame inside a notebook widget without resorting to a fixed width and height for the treeview container (frame)? I'm not sure if what I'm doing wrong here. Here is my progress so far. Also tips on how I can improve my coding are greatly appreciated.

Although I can make my treeview expand to its frame by uncommenting the line

self.tabcpfailures.grid_propagate(0) and giving a fixed width and height to the frame which I'm avoiding.

mainwindow.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tk_tooltip as ttp
import menu
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MainWindow:

def __init__(self, master):

    self.master = master
    self._menu_frame = None
    # Main GUI elements declaration

    self.frmnav = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="#182C61")
    self.menu_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="green")

    self.btndaily = self.mn_create_navbutton(
        "D", "Daily Monitoring", menu.DailyMonitoring)

    # Main GUI elements styling
    self.master.title("DETE Tool")
    self.master.config(bg="white")
    self.master.geometry("{}x{}".format(self.master.winfo_screenwidth(),
                                        self.master.winfo_screenheight()))
    self.master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frmnav.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.menu_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.menu_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.menu_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    self.btndaily.grid(row=0, column=0,
                       pady=(10, 0), padx=(5, 5))

    self.menu_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    self.btndaily.grid_propagate(0)

def mn_create_navbutton(self, text, tooltip, menu_class):

    button_placeholder = tk.Frame(self.frmnav, width=50, height=50)
    button_placeholder.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    button_placeholder.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    nav_button = tk.Button(button_placeholder, text=text, bg="#e67e22", fg="white", font=("Roboto", 10, "bold"), relief="flat",
                           command=lambda: self.mn_switch_frame(menu_class))
    nav_button_tooltip = ttp.CreateToolTip(nav_button, tooltip)
    nav_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

    return button_placeholder

def mn_center_window(self, screenwidth, screenheight):

    # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
    self.screenwidth = screenwidth
    self.screenheight = screenheight

    windowWidth = self.master.winfo_reqwidth()
    windowHeight = self.master.winfo_reqheight()

    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    positionRight = int(
        self.master.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
    positionDown = int(
        self.master.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)

    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    return self.master.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self.screenwidth, self.screenheight, positionRight, positionDown))

def mn_switch_frame(self, menu_class):

    menu_new_frame = menu_class(self.menu_frame)

    if self._menu_frame is not None:

        self._menu_frame.destroy()

    self._menu_frame = menu_new_frame
```

menu.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tk_tooltip as ttp
import db
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class DailyMonitoring(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master):

    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master

    # DailyMonitoring GUI elements declaration
    self.tabparent = ttk.Notebook(self)

    self.tabcpfailures = tk.Frame(self.tabparent)
    self.tabparent.add(self.tabcpfailures, text="CP Failures")
    self.treecpfailures = CreateTreeView(
        self.tabcpfailures, *("id", "duedate", "workflowtype", "transactionid", "batchid", "jobid"))

    self.taberroredtasks = tk.Frame(self.tabparent)
    self.tabparent.add(self.taberroredtasks, text="Errored Tasks")

    # DailyMonitoring GUI elements styling

    self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.grid_propagate(0)

    self.tabparent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.tabcpfailures.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.tabcpfailures.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #self.tabcpfailures.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    #self.tabcpfailures.grid_propagate(0)

class CreateTreeView:

def __init__(self, master, *args):

    self.master = master

    self.treemenu = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
    self.treemenu["show"] = "headings"
    self.treemenu["columns"] = args

    for arg in args:

        self.treemenu.heading(arg, text="{}".format(arg))

    self.treemenu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

How I want it to look like (this is by using a fixed width and height and uncommenting the **self.tabcpfailures.grid_propagate(0)**):

[How I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/391TH.png)

How it looks like when I want to automatically expand frame inside the notebook so the the tree should also expand as well on the entire frame using **self.tabcpfailures.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")**

[How it looks like when using sticky=nsew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Lbh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-get-a-treeview-columns-to-fit-the-frame-it-is-within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772458)

Comment: sadly it didnt :(. I'm getting the same result when using sticky=nsew on grid

Comment: Are you aware how [Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) is used for?